# Python - Prining data from lists with loop

Tags: python

I am making a program that provides quotes for painting rooms, I am trying to print back data the user inputted. I need to print the dimensions entered for each wall, for example:

- Wall 1: 5.0m x 3.0m
- Wall 2: 8.0m x 3.0m
- Wall 3: 5.0m x 3.0m
- Wall 4: 8.0m x 3.0m

I need it to loop and print a certain amount of times depending on the amount of walls inputted and then print the data from each position in the list.

I have tried so much at this point my code is a mess and doesn't make sense but this is where I am at for the displaying it back to the under. I am not that advanced with python. I think there are errors with indentation and for loops and print within them! PLEASE HELP.

```
clear = lambda: os.system ('cls')
clear()
print("Your Room details were entered as followed.")
print('')
print("Walls:", Walls)
for i in range (1,Walls):
    for x in (WallLengthArr):
        print(str("Wall", i + ":", x + "m x " + height + "m")

print("Windows:", Windows)
nextstage = input("You have completed stage 3, Press enter to continue...")
clear = lambda: os.system ('cls')
clear()
```

Comment: the `print` in the loop is missing closing parentheses. Also `"Wall", i` should be `"Wall"+ i`

Comment: You might want to use an editor that can help you with spotting basic errors like this. It will save you so much time.

Comment: okay that was a mistake I missed in this part but its no the problem, now: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: right, my bad - all your integer variables (`i`,`x` and probably `height`) should be surrounded with `str()` - or even better use proper string formatting, see e.g.: this site for some more info: https://pyformat.info/

Comment: Thank you so much I knew it would be something easy and I will look into proper string formatting!

Answer (score 0):

So there's a few issues with the code you have, the first one being that you are missing a closing parenthesis in the line:

```
print(str("Wall", i + ":", x + "m x " + height + "m")
```

The second one is that you are using `str()` wrong, however it shouldn't be necessary here at all because you are only trying to format a string, not convert some other type to a string. If you really insist on using `str` then the line should look like this:

```
print("Wall" + str(i) + ":" + str(x) + "m x " + str(height) + "m")
```

However a better and more Pythonic way of doing this would be using string formatting, so one solution would be to write the line this way:

```
print("Wall {0}: {1}m x {2}m".format(i,m,height))
```